# Add word to url if some atribute exist

Tags: jquery, string, url, attributes, tags

How can I add some word for example "test" to url(with jQuery) when on the page exist some tag include attribute 'data' ends "**-test**".

```
<body><p data="ABC123"></p></body>
```

-> nothing to add

```
<body><p data="ABC123-test"></p></body>
```

-> add **-test** behind word FIND

i.e. from www.page.com/download.php?stay=ONE-FIND-this

to

www.page.com/download.php?stay=ONE-FIND-**test**-this

I don't know all page url, but it always contains word FIND
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can probably be done better/faster but I did my best.

```
 if ($("input[data$='-test']").length){
    var currentURL = $(location).attr('href');           //Get current URL
    var index = currentURL.indexOf("FIND")+4;               //Get position of "FIND"
    var newURL = currentURL.substring(0, index) + "-test" + currentURL.substring(index);
    $(location).attr('href', newURL);
    }
```

Comment: Looks simply, but adds -test in the end.. I need add -test behind FIND (it could be in the middle of url)

Comment: Indexes might be a little wrong but I hope you understand how to do it now.

Comment: I am not really sure, but I think it will replace find to test... or am I wrong?

Comment: You should be able to make it work with the above code!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('test') > -1) {
    var text = document.location.href;
    text = text.replace("test", "Find");
    history.pushState(document.URL, "", document.URL.replace(text, ""));
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the first part with -1... can you explain this please?

Comment: to find whether url contains "test"